# Symfony routing allows commas where dots are configurated

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-3.4, symfony-http-foundation

I have a route configuration:

```
    <route id="some_route" path="/special/path/{some_strings}">
        <default key="_controller">SpecialControllerBundle:Default:index</default>
        <requirement key="some_strings">1.1|1.2|1.3</requirement>
    </route>
```

By specifications allow only `1.1`, `1.2`, `1.3` strings are valid as some_strings parameter.

So I call `myhost/special/path/1.1` - and it works just fine.

But for some reason I can call `myhost/special/path/1,1` (notice the comma) - and somehow it matches the requirements and passes data to the controller.

If I call some illegal requirement `myhost/special/path/2.3` it gives 404 as it should.

Symfony 3.4 dependencies are used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<requirement key="some_strings">1.1|1.2|1.3</requirement>
```

These are not strings that get matched literally, but as regular expressions. `.` in a regular expression means any arbitrary character. If you don’t want this special meaning, then you need to *escape* the dot, by prefixing it with a backslash.

```
<requirement key="some_strings">1\.1|1\.2|1\.3</requirement>
```